# aura:systemError event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I am trying to implement aura:systemError by going through the docs [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_systemError.htm)

but it is not working. showSystemError method in controller.js is not getting triggered.

Component:

```
    <aura:component controller="ExceptionClass" access="global" >
    <aura:handler event="aura:systemError" action="{!c.showSystemError}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="response" type="Aura.Action"/>
   <lightning:button name="clickMe" value="click me" label="click" onclick = "{!c.clickMe}"/>
   </aura:component>
```

Controller.js

```
 ({
    clickMe: function(cmp, event) {
    // Call an Apex controller that throws an error
    var action = cmp.get("c.throwError");
    action.setCallback(cmp, function(response){
        alert('hi'); // **getting called**
        cmp.set("v.response", response);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

showSystemError: function(cmp, event) {
    alert('hellllo'); // **not working**
    // Handle system error
    console.log(cmp);
    console.log(event);
}
})
```

ExceptionClass:

```
public class ExceptionClass {
@AuraEnabled
public static void throwError(){
    try{
        integer i =  1/0;
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
      throw ex;
    }
}
}
```

Does anyone have implemented it. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried capturing aura:systemError but was unsuccessfull. It looks like **aura:systemError** was in earlier API but now deprecated.

What you are trying to achieve can be done using **state** variable in response.

```
trigger: function(cmp, event) {
        // Call an Apex controller that throws an error
        var action = cmp.get("c.throwError");
        action.setCallback(cmp, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                // Alert the user with the value returned 
                // from the server
                alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
            }
            if (state === "ERROR") {
                console.log("From server: "+response.getReturnValue());
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + 
                                    errors[0].message);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
```

Whenever server side error/exception happens the state variable from response is "ERROR". You can use that to your advantage to build the catching logic or firing events to alert other components.

Comment: Thanks Pranay. I thought aura:systemError is something new, so I was trying to see how it works. And yes, you are right, we can handle exception using state.